# Sending User Input to a ListView in a different Activity

Tags: java, android

I´m new to app development and I´m trying to figure out how to send an user input like name, to a list view located in a diferent activity.

Thanks in advance.

MainActivity:

```js
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    private Button mbuttonNext;
    private EditText meditTextName;



    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        meditTextName = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editTextName);
        mbuttonNext = (Button) findViewById(R.id.buttonNext);


        mbuttonNext.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {

                Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, ClientList.class);
                startActivity(intent);

            }
        });
    }
}
```

ListViewActivity:

```js
public class ClientList extends AppCompatActivity {

    private ListView listaClientes;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_client_list);

        listaClientes = (ListView) findViewById((R.id.listView));


    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the main activity you need to need intent.putExtra

```
mbuttonNext.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, ClientList.class);
        intent.putExtra("VariableName", "Fred");
        startActivity(intent);
    }
});
```

Than in listView

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_client_list);

    listaClientes = (ListView) findViewById((R.id.listView));
    Bundle bundle = getIntent().getExtras(); //get the intent and data  passed
    //next check that bundle is not null
    if (bundle != null) {
        String name = bundle.getString("VariableName"); 
        //try loging out the value
        Log.i("Name", name);
    }

}
```

I believe this will solve your problem

Answer (score 0):

When starting the new activity:

```
Intent newIntent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, ClientList.class);
newIntent.putExtra("com.example.myapp.NAME", "someName");
startActivity(newIntent);
```

Then in ClientList:

```
Intent intent = getIntent();
String name = intent.getStringExtra("com.example.myapp.NAME");
```

Can then use name variable as source data for the ListView.

Answer (score 0):

Usually you should create an Adapter that will "set" the items in the ListView. In order for you to send/transfer the user input to another activity you can use "putExtra()". You can do that the following way:

`intent.putExtra("str1",item)`

where str1 is the key to get your item in the activity you started. To do that you should do:

```
Bundle b = getIntent().getExtras();
Obj a = (TypeCast) b.get("str1");
```

After that you should read how to create an Adapter and set it in a ListView in order for your ListView to show the item.

Comment: Thank you very much, for you explanation.